# Why node.js does not load website after a server restart?

Tags: node.js, iis, angular-universal, windows-server

I use Windows Server Standard 2019 to host an Angular 11 Universal with ASP.net Core 3.1.1 website. The website was working great until a server restart. I did many tests to make sure there is no memory leak or some error from the angular app and everything is absolutely perfect. Then I had to restart the server to install some windows updates and then the website was not working anymore. It does an infinite loading.

The thing is if I kill the **Node.js JavasScript Runtime** running in **Background processes** **which run after the server has restarted** and immediately refresh the website, Node will launch a new process and the website will works as expected until the next server restart. I made many other tests to found that specific case scenario.

So, I am not sure how to solve this. Naturally, I want the website to work immediately after a server restart without any intervention from my side. Here are the files and configurations I guess should help to aim the problem, let me know if you need other info:

Website the folder structure:

- dist (folder)
- iisnode (folder)
- main.js
- node_start.cmd
- Web.config

I installed **nodejs 14.16.0 LTS first then 15.11.0 Current** and also **Url Rewrite 2.1** and **iisnode-full-v0.2.21-x64**

The IIS is version 10. I tried setting the Application Pools to:

- Start application pool immediately
- Start mode: AlwaysRunning
- Idle Time-out Action: Suspend
- Maximum Worker Processus: 0
- Preload Enabled: True

I repeat the website works as expected when I kill the Node.js JavasScript Runtime in the background which run after the server has restarted and then hit refresh to reach the website. Finally, the website works with a valid SSL certificate.

Here the content of node_start.cmd

> cd "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\championstogether" "C:\Program
> Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\championstogether\main.js"

Then the Web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>        
      <handlers>
                <add name="StaticFilesCss" path="*.css" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />  
                <add name="StaticFilesPng" path="*.png" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read" />
        <add name="iisnode" path="main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      </handlers>
      <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --no-deprecation --no-warnings" 
        flushResponse="false" 
                promoteServerVars="HTTP_UID,HTTP_PUBCOOKIE_USER,LOGON_USER,HTTP_SHIBSESSIONID"
                node_env="production"
                nodeProcessCountPerApplication="0"
                debugHeaderEnabled="false"
                devErrorsEnabled="false"
        gracefulShutdownTimeout="60000"
        maxConcurrentRequestsPerProcess="1024"
        maxNamedPipeConnectionRetry="100"
        namedPipeConnectionRetryDelay="250"
        maxNamedPipeConnectionPoolSize="512"
        maxNamedPipePooledConnectionAge="30000"
        asyncCompletionThreadCount="0"
        initialRequestBufferSize="4096"
        maxRequestBufferSize="65536"
        uncFileChangesPollingInterval="5000"
        loggingEnabled="true"
        logDirectory="iisnode"
        debuggingEnabled="true"
        debuggerPortRange="5058-6058"
        debuggerPathSegment="debug"
        maxLogFileSizeInKB="128"
        maxTotalLogFileSizeInKB="1024"
        maxLogFiles="20"
        enableXFF="false"
        configOverrides="iisnode.yml"
                watchedFiles="web.config;*.js;routes\*.js;views\*.pug"/>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="DynamicContent">
                 <match url="/*" />
                 <action type="Rewrite" url="main.js" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="StaticContent" stopProcessing="true">  
                  <match url="([\S]+[.](jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ts|cscc|less|ico|html|map|svg))" />
                  <action type="None" />
            </rule>
         <rule name="SocketIO" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
               <match url="socket.io.+"/>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="main.js"/>
         </rule>
          <!-- Don't interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
          <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^main.js\/debug[\/]?"/>
          </rule>
       </rules>
      </rewrite>
      <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/otf" />
     </staticContent>    
    </system.webServer>
    </location>
  </configuration>
```

Thank you for any help,

Samantha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @killshot13 answer, I got nodejs to work with HttpPlatformHandler. The website takes maybe 3 minutes to load the first time after a server restart. I'm little disapointed about not being able to configure nodejs with nodeProcessCountPerApplication="0" or flushResponse="false" but perhaps someone else know how.

So here the answer :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>        
      <handlers>
        <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
      </handlers>
      <httpPlatform 
           arguments=".\main.js"
           stdoutLogEnabled="true"
           stdoutLogFile=".\node.log"
           startupTimeLimit="20"
           startupRetryCount="10"
           rapidFailsPerMinute="10"
           requestTimeout="00:02:00"
           processesPerApplication="2"
           processPath="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe --no-deprecation --no-warnings">
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
                <environmentVariable name="NODE_ENV" value="production" />
            </environmentVariables>            
        </httpPlatform>
      <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" />
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
      <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
      <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
      <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <remove fileExtension=".otf" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/x-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".otf" mimeType="application/otf" />
     </staticContent>    
    </system.webServer>
    </location>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="iisstart.htm" />
                <add value="default.aspx" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

Comment: Have you considered passing `nodeProcessCountPerApplication="0"` and/or `flushResponse="false"` under `arguments`? 

The documentation is rather vague on what exactly can be defined here; it reads as follows.

`arguments` -- "Optional string value. Arguments to the executable or script specified in the `processPath` setting. There is no default value."

Comment: This is something that should be tested with arguments, I didn't test it. Those parameters won't work with processPath. I also made the decision to switch back to iisnode and kill the Node.js JavasScript Runtime on server restart. I prefer to have access to all parameters for better performance since it will be rare the server will be restarted. Hopefully Microsoft will see this and take action.

Answer (score 1):

Samantha -

Based on your `web.config` file, I see you are using the `iisnode` module. The `iisnode` module actually has a bug that requires a manual restart of the Node.js process after a server restart, and to my knowledge, a fix has never been conclusively developed.

Although Microsoft is now in possession of the code, they did not create it, nor are they actively maintaining it. Quite frankly, I am surprised they have not already released an official notice about deprecation.

The alternative options for running `node.js` apps on IIS are either to use the ARR (reverse proxy) module or the `HttpPlatformHandler` module. ARR is extremely generic; it does not support Node.js specific variables or even a specification that Node is being used in the `web.config`.

My suggestion would be to use the `HttpPlatformHandler` module, which can manage any process, including Node, and also any proxy requests to and from the parent process. While still basically a reverse proxy, this module can be configured for a `node.js` process. The `web.config` should look something like this.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpPlatformHandler" path="main.js" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
        <httpPlatform processPath="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"
                      arguments="" 
                      startupTimeLimit=20
                      startupRetryCount=10
                      rapidFailsPerMinute=10
                      requestTimeout="00:02:00"
                      stdoutLogEnabled=true
                      stdoutLogFile="httpplatform-stdout"
                      processesPerApplication=0
                      forwardWindowsAuthToken=false>
            <environmentVariables>
                <environmentVariable name="PORT" value="%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
                <environmentVariable name="NODE_ENV" value="Production" />
            </environmentVariables>
         </httpPlatform>
     // add the config details for the rest of your module here
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

> **ADDITIONAL REFERENCES --**
>
> ***Official***
>
> > [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/windows-server-azure-pack/mt125371(v=technet.10))
> >
> > [Download & Support Page](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/httpplatformhandler)
>
> ***Community***
>
> > [Node & IIS Configuration Discussion Thread](https://dev.to/petereysermans/hosting-a-node-js-application-on-windows-with-iis-as-reverse-proxy-397b/comments)
> >
> > [Peter Eyserman's Blog Article](https://eysermans.com/post/using-http-platform-handler-to-host-a-node-js-application-via-iis)

Comment: I would never found that by myself, thank you very much! I did some try with the httpPlaform and it works great but it looks like I cannot set up most of iisnode parameters. I will show the new web.config this week-end.

Comment: I did notice that some of the constraints available with `iisnode` either do not translate directly or are completely absent from `httpplatform`. This is presumably because the latter is not Node specific and therefore a bit more generalized. Hopefully, you can either find an alternate means of enforcing said parameters or perhaps even eliminate some of them altogether.